# ASP.net Core WebAPI Routing order parameter condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got have the following controller:

```
[Route("xapi/statements")] << -- NOTICE THE ROUTE
[Produces("application/json")]
public class StatementsController : ApiControllerBase
```

With he following actions

```
/// <summary>
/// Stores a single Statement with the given id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="statementId"></param>
/// <param name="statement"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[AcceptVerbs("PUT", "POST", Order = 1)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutStatement([FromQuery]Guid statementId, [ModelBinder(typeof(StatementPutModelBinder))]Statement statement)
{

    await _mediator.Send(PutStatementCommand.Create(statementId, statement));

    return NoContent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Create statement(s) with attachment(s)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model"></param>
/// <returns>Array of Statement id(s) (UUID) in the same order as the corresponding stored Statements.</returns>
[HttpPost(Order = 2)]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<Guid>>> PostStatements(StatementsPostModelBinder model)
{
    ICollection<Guid> guids = await _mediator.Send(CreateStatementsCommand.Create(model.Statements));

    return Ok(guids);
}
```

The actions are executed in the following order:
1. PutStatement
2. PostStatements

But PutStatement should only be triggered if the statementId parameter is provided. This is not the case.

I'm using 2 model binders to parse the content of the streams as either application/json or multipart/form-data if the statements have any attachments.
1. StatementPutModelBinder
2. StatementsPostModelBinder

How do i prevent the action from being excuted if the statementId parameter is not provided?
Eg. /xapi/statements/ => Hits PutStatement

Comment: If you're not providing a statementId, then I'm assuming that your `Statement` model will also be missing that?

Comment: According to the xAPI specs its optional on the statement model, but if provided they must be equal. This happends during the mediator pipeline where i have provided validation for each command.

Comment: You can check in your StatementPutModelBinder that statementid is not an empty guid, if it is reject it or dont you want a badrequest result for it?

Comment: If the request is /xapi/statements?statementId=000..-000 
Then the request is rejected because the statementId is null, empty or doesnt match the optional id on the statement model.
But if the request is /xapi/statements, the PutStatement is hit. Which is not what i want. It should hit the PostStatements if the method is POST, else its bad request.

Comment: Ye, you have a bit of a tricky situation. You accept both put and post to an endpoint and then accept post to another endpoint that is basically the same route. I would remove accepting post for the first endpoint and make statementid part of the route i.e Route("{statementId:guid}"). This will force an id for put, which is what you want and then make your post handle empty statementId fromquery

Comment: Yeah, i would like to do that. But the xAPI specs requires that there is a statementId parameter. See the following source: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Communication.md#211-put-statements

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a answer for my own question, but i made a mistake and was under the impression that the xAPI statements resource should allow statementId as a parameter for POST requests. Therefore i do not have the issue any more, which started my question.